# Bootstrap - Scrollbar issue with moving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to prevent my page from moving when i open a modal which is caused from the scrollbar. Originally the page would keep moving several pixels to the left and not move back each time i opened a new modal. I had to apply this css to solve that problem:

```
padding-right:0px !important;
margin-right:0px !important;
```

But now even though the page shifts back, when either the login modal or register modal is open and you press 'Sign up here', or 'Sign in here' from the loginmodal or registermodal, the scrollbar hides and then reappears which shifts the page before moving back to its original position. I experimented briefly and added overflow:scroll to the element, i didn't like the idea of the two scroll bars when the page is below a certain resolution.

So my question is:

> How do i stop the scrollbar from hiding and reappearing when opening a modal when another model is already open which causes the page to shift left then back to its original position.

Here is my JSFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/w07dx8jk/

**EDIT:**

Would it be possible to have a blank scrollbar visible when a modal is open to stop it from disappearing which causes the shifting or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you simply leave the scrollbar visible, so it won't flicker:

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: Thank you. When shrinking to a very small resolution there is another scrollbar but this wont be view-able on mobile devices anyway which i didn't think about at the time. Thank you very much , and sorry for being slightly stupid this is my first project i have started so i'm still learning :)

Comment: I would also add `#loginmodal { overflow-y: hidden; }`

To remove the inactive scroll bar when the login modal is open.

Comment: Does the same apply to the #registermodal ?

Comment: Yeah include it for the `#registermodal` as well. (Didn't realise that was implemented)

Comment: In that case it would just be easier to add the rule to `.modal`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `overflow-y: scroll !important` to `body` to prevent the page move, `!important` is required because Bootstrap applies some of its own CSS to `body` and you need to override them.

And then apply `overflow: hidden` to `.modal` to prevent the double scrollbars.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/w07dx8jk/1/